# How changes will take effect on child theme function. php or theme's functions.php file?

Tags: wordpress, passwords

Now I have a child theme in WordPress. If I want to make additions in theme level. What I will do? Change in Child Theme function. php or theme's functions.php

Right now, I'm confuse at what point I have to start?
Should I start to work on child theme file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should start to work on the child theme file. The [WordPress Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#using-functions-php) explains how to use the functions.php file in your child theme. It says to add a PHP function to your theme, you should add the function to the functions.php of your child theme. This WordPress page on [Child Themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#using-functions-php) will help you to understand the relationship between parent and child themes.